# UnitTest WorkflowInstanceID Exception

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation, accessor, instanceid, workflow-foundation-3

I am unit testing a StateMachineWorkflow and I create my test methods by clicking in my test project and I make Add - UnitTest. In the project window I select the workflow that I want to test and all the methods in it.

Visual Studio generated a Test Reference folder in my Test Project with an accessor to the workflow. It also generated all the TestMethod() necessary for the testing. All test Methods use a MyWorkflow_Accessor target = new MyWorkflow_Accessor(). When I need to call a function I just do something like target.SendEmail().

Everything works fine, except for one thing: **I can't use WorkflowInstanceId of the Workflow**, when the code reach a line that uses this it throws an exception in the Workflow, "**This is an invalid design time operation. You can only perform the operation at runtime.**"
Is it possible to inject the WorkflowID by code? Is there any workaround to this situation? I use the WorkflowInstanceId in a lot of functions and changing the Workflow code to match my test doesn't seem like a good idea because I believe the problem is in the test and not in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you're using WF 3.5 or WF4 with the state machine update. For the latter, you can use [Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/) to test workflows.

It sounds like you're using WF 3.5, though. If this is new development, I would seriously consider moving to WF4. Microsoft basically rewrote WF, and the sooner you switch, the easier your migration path will be.

Otherwise, there is some information on [testing with WF 3.5 on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2008/12/01/new-virtual-lab-using-test-first-development-with-wf-3-5.aspx).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am using WF 3.5. and working with Visual Studio 2010. Moving to WF 4.0 will be hard because the project I am working on is very advanced. I was trying to take advantage of the Accessor that the unit test generate, but so far I have no luck because I can access the functions inside de workflow but the thing like WorkflowInstanceID dont work when I call them by the accessor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with WF 3.5. Perhaps someone else can suggest a solution.